# Extract specific string from image in android using google cloud vision Api

Tags: android, android-studio, image-processing, google-cloud-platform, text-extraction

I am working on application where I am entering data by capturing or selecting images to keep user interaction minimum and application will read data or text in an image. I want to extract any price of product in the image and for that I am using google's cloud vision API. it is working very well but it extracts all the text in an image. How can I extract just pricing information such as any string contaning $,Rs,euro sign etc from that image? Here is my code for selecting image from gallery and extracting text from it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //SurfaceView cameraView;
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button select , take ;
    ImageButton process;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE=100;
    Uri image_URI;
    // CameraSource cameraSource;
    final int  RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;
    Bitmap bitmap ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // inialize all the views
        process = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.process);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_text);
        imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select);
        take = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take);

        // set listener of take photo button
        take.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //set listener of select photo button
        select.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openGallery(); // call openGallery function
                    }
                });

        //set listener of button which will process the image ie extract text from it
        process.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
                if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Detector is not available yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = textRecognizer.detect(frame);
                if (items.size() != 0) {
                    textView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                                TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                            }
                            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });


    }



    private void openGallery(){

        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery,PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    //
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode==PICK_IMAGE){
            image_URI = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(image_URI);
            try {
                InputStream pic = getContentResolver().openInputStream(image_URI);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(pic);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex to match. Use [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) to test regex.

**Try this:**

```
private void getCurrencyFromString(String string) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]?[\$€¥])?\s?(\d{1,3}((,\d{1,3})+)?(.\d{1,3})?(.\d{1,3})?(,\d{1,3})?)",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(string);
    Set<String> currency = new HashSet<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {

        Log.d(TAG, "getCurrencyFromString " + currency);
    }

}
```